# 3D image to 2D plane transformation - Chessboard

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, affinetransform, homography

I'm trying to create a 2D floor plan from an image taken from a upper angle:
[image: Original]

Currently, I'm creating a warped image, using the [warpPerspective()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gaf73673a7e8e18ec6963e3774e6a94b87) function from OpenCV.

However, looking at the resulting top-view image, the checkerboard is shifted away from the kitchen counter. This is due to the perspective of the camera. The result is the following:
[image: image3]

Instead, I would like to have the checkerboard right next to the kitchen counter as it is the case in reality. Similar to this:
[image: image4]

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this or how to deal with the shifting of the image due to the camera perspective?

Comment: A single Homography isn't suited for that. You will need some kind of 3D reconstruction or you have to define every 3D plane in the image as a single homography.

Comment: @Micka  thank you for your suggestion!

Considering that the homography of the reference plane 1 (ground plane) is known, do you have any idea how to derive the "second" plane 2 (kitchen counter plane) from the ground plane?

Comment: I don't think this is realistically automatically possible